# A small problem when using "Tidy" to format JS in the "Code Sandbox" if the code uses "dynamic import"

Tags: bug, stack-snippets

When creating an [answer to the question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70467212/transform-javascript-string-with-import-statement-into-a-function-in-the-brows/70468362#70468362), I drew attention to the incorrect formatting of the JS code via "Tidy" in "Code Snippet" when using "[dynamic import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports)" in the code.

For example, take an example from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#dynamic_imports) using `await` and dynamic `import()`:

```js
let module = await import('/modules/my-module.js');
```

If we click "Tidy" in the Code Sandbox, this code is converted to:

```
let module = await
import ('/modules/my-module.js');
```

The bug is probably not dangerous and you can manually correct the code after formatting, but I think it's worth paying attention to it.

Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Already reported on MSO: [Update JS-Beautify Snippet formatter](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/401901/4642212).